# Twitch API redirect_mismatch

Tags: php, api, laravel-4, twitch

I'm busy with the Twitch API since yesterday, had a simple authentication working, with redirect uri:

```
http://localhost:8000/redirect
```

Now i've changed the redirect uri to:

```
http://localhost:8000/connect/twitch
```

And it's not working anymore.

I've change the uri in the twitch app dashboard, and in the requests, but I still get the "Redirect_Mismatch".

What am I doing wrong?

Twitch Model:

```
class Twitch{

    var $client;
    var $oauth_token;

    public function __construct($token = null)
    {
        $this->client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

        if($token != null) $this->setOAuthToken($token);
    }

    public function retrieveOAuthToken($code)
    {
        $res = $this->client->post('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token', [
            'body' => [
                'client_id'     => Config::get('twitch.client_id'),
                'client_secret' => Config::get('twitch.client_secret'),
                'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
                'redirect_uri'  => Config::get('twitch.redirect_uri'),
                'code'          => $code
            ],
            'verify'            => false
        ]);

        $result = json_decode($res->getBody());
        $this->oauth_token = $result->access_token;
    }
}
```

Laravel Twitch Config file:

```
return array(

    'client_id' => 'REMOVED',

    'client_secret' => 'REMOVED',

    'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost:8000/twitch',

);
```

Controller:

```
class ConnectController extends \BaseController {

    public function twitch()
    {
        $twitch = new Twitch();
        $twitch->retrieveOAuthToken(Input::get('code'));
    }
}
```

Twitch App Settings:

[Twitch Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95XFq.jpg)

Comment: Your Laravel seems to be pointing at the wrong address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your laravel config:

```
return array(
    'client_id' => 'REMOVED',
    'client_secret' => 'REMOVED',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost:8000/connect/twitch',
);
```

And you twitch redirect URI by *http://localhost:8000/connect/twitch*.

If one one the 2 URLs (Laravel or Twitch settings) is different from the other, you will have the **Redirect_Mismatch**

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the Twitch JS sdk initialised on http://localhost:8000/twitch as well. Im not sure about Laravel etc, but in this case try add the Twitch class on that page as well if that is how Twitch is initialised.